# How do I disable persistence (caching) for firestore on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, sqlite, google-cloud-firestore

My application will work offline for weeks, I structured all SQLite and I will send the documents when I have an internet connection.

```
FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
        .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
        .build();
db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

I followed the example above as in the documentation, but when I connect to the internet it executes all the commands when I was offline

Answer (score 1):

If you disable persistence, that doesn't stop Firestore from trying to synchronize changes made while temporarily offline.  If there is a blip in connectivity, the SDK will not fail the write immediately - it will retry while the app process is still running.  Disabling persistence disables the ability for it to synchronize changes made while offline, *after the app process is killed and restarted*, as that requires a write to local storage to persist the information about the data to write.

If you want writes to completely fail immediately while offline, you should probably not use the SDK at all, and instead direct all writes through a backend API endpoint that performs the write on behalf of the client app.  That way, the request will fail if there is no connectivity, and you can choose what to do about that in app's code.